# Why is my calculator adding the digits of its input together instead of updating to a multi-digit number?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I am making a simple calculator and so far its working pretty decently for me besides when I try to enter a digit larger than 9. If I put in 11+55 it will save the firstNumber as 2 and the secondNumber as 10 and return 12 when I obviously want it to save 11 and 55 and return 66.

Thank you in advance to anyone who takes their time to help me out! =)

I'm honestly very new to all of this but am pretty sure the issue is somewhere in my results function at the top of my js file but have been getting majorly confused by it. It seems like it is adding somewhere that it is supposed to be concatenating?

Here is what I'm working with...

```
  <body>
    <h2>Calculator</h2>
    <div class="top">
      Output will show up here
      <p id="calculations"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">  
      <button id="one" onclick="results(1)">1</button>
      <button id="two" onclick="results(2)">2</button>
      <button id="three" onclick="results(3)">3</button>
      <button id="subtraction" onclick="setOperator(`-`)">-</button>
      <button id="four" onclick="results(4)">4</button>
      <button id="five" onclick="results(5)">5</button>
      <button id="six" onclick="results(6)">6</button>
      <button id="addition" onclick="setOperator(`+`)">+</button>
      <button id="seven" onclick="results(7)">7</button>
      <button id="eight" onclick="results(8)">8</button>
      <button id="nine" onclick="results(9)">9</button>
      <button id="divison" onclick="setOperator(`/`)">/</button>
      <button id="zero" onclick="results(0)">0</button>
      <button id="enter" onclick="enterButton()">Enter</button>
      <button id="clear" onclick="clearResults()">Clear</button>
      <button id="mulitplication" onclick="setOperator(`*`)">*</button>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>



let firstNumber = null;
let secondNumber = null;
let operator = null;
let result = null;

function results(input) {
    document.getElementById("calculations").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', (input));
  
    if (operator === null) {
      // If operator is null, update firstNumber
      if (firstNumber === null) {
        firstNumber = input;
      } else {
        firstNumber += input;
      }
    } else {
      // If operator is not null, update secondNumber
      if (secondNumber === null) {
        secondNumber = input;
      } else {
        secondNumber += input;
      }
    }
  }


function calculateResult() {
  if (firstNumber === null || secondNumber === null) {
    return null;
  }
  
  const num1 = Number(firstNumber);
  const num2 = Number(secondNumber);
  
  if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
    return null;
  }

  switch (operator) {
    case "+":
      return Number(firstNumber) + Number(secondNumber);
    case "-":
      return Number(firstNumber) - Number(secondNumber);
    case "*":
      return Number(firstNumber) * Number(secondNumber);
    case "/":
      return Number(firstNumber) / Number(secondNumber);
    default:
      return null;
  }
}

function enterButton() {
  if (result === null) {
  // Calculate the result and update the calculations element
  const result = calculateResult();
  if (result !== null) {
    document.getElementById("calculations").innerHTML = result;
  }
}
    // Set firstNumber to the result, and reset secondNumber and operator
    firstNumber = result;
    secondNumber = null;
    operator = null;
  }
```

Comment: well you are doing 1 + 1 so it is going to be 2. You need to concat them as strings, if you do not want them to be added together.

Comment: Why do you expect 1+1 to be 11? (Note that indeed "1" + "1"  is "11", but that not what is written in your not-so [MRE] )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing a number to the `results()` function, in your inline  `onclick` handler for your digits e.g. `onclick="results(1)"`, you will either have to cast the input to a string:

```js
function results(input) {
  document.getElementById("calculations").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', input);
  const inputAsString = `${input}`; // cast to a string

  if (operator === null) {
    // If operator is null, update firstNumber
    if (firstNumber === null) {
      firstNumber = inputAsString;
    } else {
      firstNumber += inputAsString; // string concatenation
    }
  } else {
    // If operator is not null, update secondNumber
    if (secondNumber === null) {
      secondNumber = inputAsString;
    } else {
      secondNumber += inputAsString; // string concatenation
    }
  }
}
```

Or pass in a string (quoted number):

```html
<button id="one" onclick="results('1')">1</button>
```

### Edit

As for your follow-up question, you need to store the result in the `firstNumber` variable as a string. You should treat the `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` variables as typed (string) variables. If you were using TypeScript, the IDE and compiler would complain about this. I changed the `enterButton()` function to the following:

```js
function enterButton() {
  // Calculate the result and update the calculations element
  const result = calculateResult();
  if (result !== null) {
    document.getElementById("calculations").innerHTML = result;
    // Set firstNumber to the result
    firstNumber = `${result}`; // store as string
  }
  // Reset secondNumber and operator
  secondNumber = null;
  operator = null;
}
```

I also removed the global `result`, because it was pointless and shared the same name as locally-scope variables.

#### Working example

```js
const displayEl = document.getElementById("calculations");

let firstNumber = null;  // string
let secondNumber = null; // string
let operator = null;     // string

function results(input) {
  displayEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', input);
  const inputAsString = `${input}`; // cast to a string

  if (operator === null) {
    // If operator is null, update firstNumber
    if (firstNumber === null) {
      firstNumber = inputAsString;
    } else {
      firstNumber += inputAsString;
    }
  } else {
    // If operator is not null, update secondNumber
    if (secondNumber === null) {
      secondNumber = inputAsString;
    } else {
      secondNumber += inputAsString;
    }
  }
}

function clearResults() {
  document.getElementById("calculations").innerHTML = "";
  firstNumber = null;
  secondNumber = null;
  operator = null;
  result = null;
}

function calculateResult() {
  console.log(firstNumber, secondNumber);
  if (firstNumber === null || secondNumber === null) {
    return null;
  }

  const num1 = Number(firstNumber);
  const num2 = Number(secondNumber);

  if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
    return null;
  }

  switch (operator) {
    case "+":
      return Number(firstNumber) + Number(secondNumber);
    case "-":
      return Number(firstNumber) - Number(secondNumber);
    case "*":
      return Number(firstNumber) * Number(secondNumber);
    case "/":
      return Number(firstNumber) / Number(secondNumber);
    default:
      return null;
  }
}

function enterButton() {
  // Calculate the result and update the calculations element
  const result = calculateResult();
  if (result !== null) {
    document.getElementById("calculations").innerHTML = result;
    // Set firstNumber to the result
    firstNumber = `${result}`; // store as string
  }
  // Reset secondNumber and operator
  secondNumber = null;
  operator = null;
}

function setOperator(op) {
  // Set the value of the operator
  if (firstNumber !== null && operator === null) {
    operator = op;
    document.getElementById("calculations").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', op);
  } else if (secondNumber !== null && operator !== null) {
    const result = calculateResult();
    if (result !== null) {
      document.getElementById("calculations").innerHTML = result + op;
      firstNumber = result;
      secondNumber = null;
      operator = op;
    }
  } else if (firstNumber !== null && operator !== null && secondNumber === null) {
    operator = op;
    document.getElementById("calculations").innerHTML = firstNumber + op;
  }
}
```

```css
#calculations {
  min-height: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<h2>Calculator</h2>
<div class="top">
  Output will show up here
  <p id="calculations"></p>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="one" onclick="results(1)">1</button>
  <button id="two" onclick="results(2)">2</button>
  <button id="three" onclick="results(3)">3</button>
  <button id="subtraction" onclick="setOperator(`-`)">-</button>
  <button id="four" onclick="results(4)">4</button>
  <button id="five" onclick="results(5)">5</button>
  <button id="six" onclick="results(6)">6</button>
  <button id="addition" onclick="setOperator(`+`)">+</button>
  <button id="seven" onclick="results(7)">7</button>
  <button id="eight" onclick="results(8)">8</button>
  <button id="nine" onclick="results(9)">9</button>
  <button id="divison" onclick="setOperator(`/`)">/</button>
  <button id="zero" onclick="results(0)">0</button>
  <button id="enter" onclick="enterButton()">Enter</button>
  <button id="clear" onclick="clearResults()">Clear</button>
  <button id="mulitplication" onclick="setOperator(`*`)">*</button>
</div>
```

Comment: omg I love you thank you so much haha!! I knew it was something simple like that but I've been trying to figure it out for hours and have felt so dumb haha.

Comment: There's something still wrong with the sequence `1, +, 1, =, 1, +, 1, =`. You'd expect 21+1=22 on the second, but it does 1+1=2

Comment: (const result shadows the global in enterButton, so the global is always null)

Comment: @Kaia I updated the `enterButton()` function above, see the update.