# Stringing multiple numbers on a calcuator

Tags: javascript, calculator

I am building a calculator, having got to the final challenge of The Odin Project: Foundations.  I had no problem with the course until this project.  I am stuck at a very specific part.

The calculator currently works if there are two numbers + an operator.  But over the last couple of days I have been stumped with getting it to work with inputting more than two numbers in a row, before pressing equals e.g. 2 + 2 * 3 = 12.

Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

```js
const numButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".num-button");
const clearButton = document.querySelector(".clear-button");
const deleteButton = document.querySelector(".delete-button");
const operatorButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".op-button");
const equalsButton = document.querySelector(".equals-button");
const display = document.querySelector("p");

let displayValue = "";
display.innerText = 0;
let previousNumber = "";

// Calculator Functions

function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function subtract(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

function multiply(a, b) {
  return a * b;
}

function divide(a, b) {
  return a / b;
}

let firstNumber = "";
let secondNumber = "";
let operator = "";
let total = "";

function operate(op, num1, num2) {
  if (op === "+") return add(num1, num2);
  if (op === "-") return subtract(num1, num2);
  if (op === "*") return multiply(num1, num2);
  if (op === "/") return divide(num1, num2);
}

numButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const clickedNumber = event.target.value;
    if (operator === "" && secondNumber === "") {
      firstNumber = parseFloat(firstNumber + clickedNumber);
      console.log("firstNumber", firstNumber);
      displayValue = firstNumber.toString();
    } else {
      secondNumber = parseFloat(secondNumber + clickedNumber);
      console.log("secondNumber", secondNumber);
      displayValue = secondNumber.toString();
    }

     if (firstNumber !== "" && secondNumber !== "") {
       firstNumber = operate(operator, firstNumber, secondNumber);
       secondNumber = "";
       secondNumber = parseFloat(secondNumber + clickedNumber);
       displayValue = secondNumber.toString();
     }

    display.innerText = displayValue;
  });
});

// Operator Buttons - This gets the operator as a string - works fine
operatorButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    operator = event.target.value;
  });
});

// Equals button - works with two numbers
equalsButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  displayValue = operate(operator, firstNumber, secondNumber);
  display.innerText = operate(operator, firstNumber, secondNumber);
  total = operate(operator, firstNumber, secondNumber);
});

// Clear button - works fine
clearButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  displayValue = "";
  display.innerText = 0;
  firstNumber = "";
  secondNumber = "";
  operator = "";
});
```

```css
.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 800px;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  align-items: center;
}

.display {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 170px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
}

.buttons-container {
  flex: 0;
}

.top-buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  margin: 5px;
}

.buttons-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 5px;
}

.clear-button,
.delete-button {
  width: 50px;
}

button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="outer-container">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="display"></p>
        <div class="buttons-container">
          <div class="top-buttons">
            <button class="clear-button">Clear</button>
            <button class="delete-button">Delete</button>
          </div>
          <div class="buttons-row">
            <button class="num-button" value="7" id="button7">7</button>
            <button class="num-button" value="8" id="button8">8</button>
            <button class="num-button" value="9" id="button9">9</button>
            <button class="op-button" value="/">÷</button>
          </div>
          <div class="buttons-row">
            <button class="num-button" value="4" id="button4">4</button>
            <button class="num-button" value="5" id="button5">5</button>
            <button class="num-button" value="6" id="button6">6</button>
            <button class="op-button" value="*">x</button>
          </div>
          <div class="buttons-row">
            <button class="num-button" value="1" id="button1">1</button>
            <button class="num-button" value="2" id="button2">2</button>
            <button class="num-button" value="3" id="button3">3</button>
            <button class="op-button" value="-">-</button>
          </div>
          <div class="buttons-row">
            <button class="num-button" value="0" id="button0">0</button>
            <button class="num-button" value=".">.</button>
            <button class="equals-button">=</button>
            <button class="op-button" value="+">+</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It is the "numButtons.forEach" section that i've been focusing on to resolve the issue. The first "if statement" works fine and calculates the answer if only two numbers and an operator are provided before pressing equals.

I've then been trying to create another "if statement" for when "firstNumber" and "secondNumber" are not empty strings, then assign the "operate" function call to "firstNumber" (which should provide the calculation of the previous numbers).  But every time I try to add a new number, it concatenates onto the "secondNumber".  Eg: 5 + 5 + 5 = 60 (5 for the firstNumber + 55 for the secondNumber).

Also, I'm not sure why but this additional code block prevents me from inputting multiple digits for the secondNumber; I can only input one (if I hide this "if statement" I can enter multiple digits again.

I hope that makes sense.  Help would be appreciated!

Comment: *"The calculator currently works if there are two numbers + an operator"*: I don't think it does. Try `1 + 1 = `.

Comment: Thanks for responding trincot.  I forgot to mention that the second if statement messes up the previous code.  If it's hidden your calculation will work.

Comment: Also, there is no possibility to enter "." in the display?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I currently replaced my original codeblock when I was trying to resolve the issue and never replaced the code for the decimal.

Comment: There is too much wrong here. This essentially comes down to rewriting the code to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to design is a scientific calculator. This would be a little more advanced compared to a simple calculator.

In order to deal with order of operations, you would need to convert the expression to an abstract syntax tree (AST) as demonstrated below. Once you have an AST, you can evaluate it.

```js
const
  DEBUG_MODE = true,
  DEFAULT_EXPRESSION = 'a + b * c',
  DEFAULT_VARIABLES = { a: 2, b: 2, c: 3 };

const
  inputEl = document.querySelector('#expression'),
  variablesEl = document.querySelector('#variables'),
  outputEl = document.querySelector('#expanded'),
  preOrderEl = document.querySelector('#pre-order'),
  postOrderEl = document.querySelector('#post-order');

inputEl.value = DEFAULT_EXPRESSION;
variablesEl.value = JSON.stringify(DEFAULT_VARIABLES, null, 2);

function main() {
  inputEl.addEventListener('input', update);
  variablesEl.addEventListener('input', update);
  update();
}

function update() {
  const
    expression = inputEl.value.trim(),
    variables = JSON.parse(variablesEl.value),
    tree = buildTree(`(${expression})`),
    answer = solve(tree, variables),
    expanded = groupedString(tree).replace(/[a-z]/ig, g => variables[g] ?? g);

  updateDisplay(preOrderEl, preOrderTraversal, tree);
  updateDisplay(postOrderEl, postOrderTraversal, tree);

  outputEl.textContent = `${expanded} = ${answer}`;
}

function updateDisplay(el, traversal, tree) {
  el.textContent = '';
  traversal(tree, (node) => {
    el.textContent += node.value;
  });
}

function solve(tree, lookup) {
  const treeCopy = cloneNode(tree);
  if (DEBUG_MODE) {
    printTree(treeCopy);
  }
  expandValues(treeCopy, lookup);
  if (DEBUG_MODE) {
    printTree(treeCopy);
  }
  rollupTree(treeCopy);
  return treeCopy.value;
}

function expandValues(tree, lookup) {
  postOrderTraversal(tree, (node) => {
    if (node.type === 'OPERAND') {
      node.value = lookup[node.value] ?? node.value;
      node.type = 'VALUE';
    }
  });
}

function getValue(node, defaultValue = 0) {
  return node != null ? (node.value ?? defaultValue) : defaultValue;
}

function rollupTree(tree) {
  postOrderTraversal(tree, (node) => {
    if (node.type === 'OPERATOR') {
      node.value = computeValue(node.value, getValue(node.left), getValue(node.right));
      node.type = 'VALUE';
      node.left = null;
      node.right = null;
    }
  });
}

function computeValue(op, left, right) {
  switch (op) {
    case '^': return left ** right;
    case '*':  return left * right;
    case '/': return left / right;
    case '+':  return left + right;
    case '-': return left - right;
  }
  return 0;
}

function buildTree(s) {
  let nodeStack = new Stack();
  let characterStack = new Stack();
  let topNode, nodeRight, nodeLeft;

  // Prioritising the operators
  let priority = new Array(123);
  priority['+'.charCodeAt()] = priority['-'.charCodeAt()] = 1;
  priority['/'.charCodeAt()] = priority['*'.charCodeAt()] = 2;
  priority['^'.charCodeAt()] = 3;
  priority[')'.charCodeAt()] = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    const ch = s[i];
    const charCode = ch.charCodeAt();
    if (ch === '(') {
      characterStack.push(ch); // Push '(' in char stack
    } else if ((/[a-zA-Z]/).test(ch)) {
      // Push the operands in node stack
      topNode = newNode('OPERAND', ch);
      nodeStack.push(topNode);
    } else if (priority[charCode] > 0) {
      // If an operator with lower or same associativity appears
      while (!characterStack.isEmpty() &&
        characterStack.peek() !== '(' &&
        (
          (ch !== '^' &&
            priority[characterStack.peek().charCodeAt()] >=
            priority[charCode]) ||
          (ch === '^' &&
            priority[characterStack.peek().charCodeAt()] >
            priority[charCode]))) {

        // Get and remove the top element from the character stack
        topNode = newNode('OPERATOR', characterStack.pop());
        topNode.right = nodeStack.pop();
        topNode.left = nodeStack.pop();
        nodeStack.push(topNode); // Push the node to the node stack
      }
      characterStack.push(ch); // Push s[i] to char stack
    } else if (ch === ')') {
      while (!characterStack.isEmpty() && characterStack.peek() !== '(') {
        topNode = newNode('OPERATOR', characterStack.pop());
        topNode.right = nodeStack.pop();
        topNode.left = nodeStack.pop();
        nodeStack.push(topNode);
      }
      characterStack.pop();
    }
  }
  topNode = nodeStack.peek();
  return topNode;
}

function newNode(type, value) {
  return new TreeNode(type, value);
}

function cloneNode(node) {
  if (node == null) {
    return null;
  }
  return Object.assign(newNode(node.type, node.value), {
    left: cloneNode(node.left),
    right: cloneNode(node.right)
  });
}

function preOrderTraversal(node, visitor, depth = 0) {
  if (node == null) {
    return;
  }
  visitor(node, depth);
  preOrderTraversal(node.left, visitor, depth + 1);
  preOrderTraversal(node.right, visitor, depth + 1);
}

function inOrderTraversal(node, visitor, depth = 0) {
  if (node == null) {
    return;
  }
  inOrderTraversal(node.left, visitor, depth + 1);
  visitor(node, depth);
  inOrderTraversal(node.right, visitor, depth + 1);
}

function postOrderTraversal(node, visitor, depth = 0) {
  if (node == null) {
    return;
  }
  postOrderTraversal(node.left, visitor, depth + 1);
  postOrderTraversal(node.right, visitor, depth + 1);
  visitor(node, depth);
}

function groupedString(node) {
  if (node === null) {
    return '';
  }
  if (node.type === 'OPERATOR') {
    return '(' + groupedString(node.left) + node.value + groupedString(node.right) + ')';
  }
  return node.value;
}

function printTree(tree) {
  const matrix = [];
  inOrderTraversal(tree, (node, depth) => {
    const buffer = Array.from({ length: 100 });
    buffer[depth] = node.value;
    matrix.push(buffer);
  });
  console.log(transpose(matrix)
    .filter(buffer => buffer.some(v => v != null))
    .map(buffer => buffer.map(v => v || '_').join('')).join('\n'));
}


function transpose(matrix) {
  return matrix[0].map((_, colIndex) => matrix.map(row => row[colIndex]));
}

class TreeNode {
  constructor(type,value) {
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
    this.type = type;
    this.value = value;
  }
}

class Stack {
  constructor() {
    this.items = [];
  }
  push(element) {
    this.items.push(element);
  }
  pop() {
    if (this.isEmpty()) {
      throw new Error('Stack underflow');
    }
    return this.items.pop();
  }
  peek() {
    return this.items[this.items.length - 1];
  }
  isEmpty() {
    return this.items.length === 0;
  }
  toArray() {
    return this.items;
  }
}

main();
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 1rem; }
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; background: #222; color: #EEE; }
body { display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center; gap: 2rem; }
#grid { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto); gap: 1rem; }
#grid div:nth-child(odd) { font-weight: bold; text-align: right; }
#grid div:nth-child(odd)::after { content: ':'; }
#grid div:nth-child(even) { font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="expression" />
<textarea id="variables" rows="12" cols="20"></textarea>
<div id="grid">
  <div>Expanded</div>
  <div id="expanded"></div>
  <div>Polish Notation</div>
  <div id="pre-order"></div>
  <div>Reverse-Polish Notation</div>
  <div id="post-order"></div>
</div>
```

Most calculators evaluate soon as you choose a second operator.

For example, I have created a calculator that stores a buffer (previously computed value) and the current operator.

```js
let buffer, operator;

const compute = (operator, left, right) => {
  switch (operator) {
    case '+': return left + right;
    case '-': return left - right;
    case '*': return left * right;
    case '/': return left / right;
    default:  return 'ERR';
  }
}

const handleClick = (e) => {
  const calculator = e.target.closest('.calculator');
  const dispBuffer = calculator.querySelector('.display > .buffer');
  const dispInput = calculator.querySelector('.display > input');
  
  switch (e.target.dataset.type) {
    case 'digit':
      dispInput.value += e.target.dataset.value;
      break;
    case 'operator':
      buffer = operator ? compute(operator, +buffer, +dispInput.value) : dispInput.value;
      operator = e.target.dataset.value;
      dispInput.value = '';
      dispBuffer.textContent = `${buffer} ${operator}`;
      break;
    case 'command':
      switch (e.target.dataset.value) {
        case 'AC':
          dispInput.value = '';
          operator = '';
          buffer = '';
          dispBuffer.textContent = '';
          break;
        case '+/-':
          dispInput.value = +dispInput.value * -1;
          break;
        case '%':
          dispInput.value = buffer ? +dispInput.value / 100 : 0;
          break;
        case '=':
          dispInput.value = compute(operator, +buffer, +dispInput.value);
          operator = '';
          buffer = '';
          dispBuffer.textContent = '';
          break;
      }
      break;
  }
};

document.querySelector('.keyboard').addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #222;
}

.calculator {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: thin solid #DDD;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  background: #444;
}

.display {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #000;
}

.display .buffer {
  min-height: 1rem;
  text-align: right;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: smaller;
}

.display > input {
  text-align: right;
  background: transparent;
  color: #FFF;
  border: none;
}

.keyboard {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  gap: 0.25rem;
}

.keyboard button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.grid-span-2 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
  <div class="display">
    <div class="buffer"></div>
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="0" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="keyboard">
    <button data-type="command" data-value="AC">AC</button>
    <button data-type="command" data-value="+/-">+/-</button>
    <button data-type="command" data-value="%">%</button>
    <button data-type="operator" data-value="/">/</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value="7">7</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value="8">8</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value="9">9</button>
    <button data-type="operator" data-value="*">*</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value="4">4</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value="5">5</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value="6">6</button>
    <button data-type="operator" data-value="-">-</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value="1">1</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value="2">2</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value="3">3</button>
    <button data-type="operator" data-value="+">+</button>
    <button class="grid-span-2" data-type="digit" data-value="0">0</button>
    <button data-type="digit" data-value=".">.</button>
    <button data-type="command" data-value="=">=</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

### References

- AST: https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/vn6fax49/
- Calculator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76637784/1762224
- Another calculator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76048483/1762224

Comment: Thanks Mr. Polywhirl I'll see if I can apply it to my code.  I think I will probably need to re-write my code for the aforementioned section.